# problem in connecting to server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
C:\Users\shilps\Desktop>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin

C:\Users\shilps\Desktop>javac Populate.java

C:\Users\shilps\Desktop>SET CLASSPATH = .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar

C:\Users\shilps\Desktop>java Populate db.properties flights.data reservations.data


Cannot connect to database server
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Populate.Populate_dbconnect(Populate.java:47)
        at Populate.<init>(Populate.java:35)
        at Populate.main(Populate.java:28)
```

how do I get rid of this error?why it is not connecting?

Comment: how do I get rid of this error?why it is not connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use -cp parameter, i.e.

```
java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar Populate db.properties flights.data reservations.data
```